# Nodejs server ignores my android app connections but accepts it if it is the same request from mobile chrome browser?

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io, android-volley

I have a strange problem,every thin was working like a charm until suddenly the NodeJs server decides to not accept my requests and log anything.I turned off the firewall nut yet is still exist.I tested to send a get request by the chrome browser but I got a response.The android app the I built seems to not getting accepted by it's server and no it is not a permission problem goes it was working before so whats going on here?!!

Even this simple NodeJS code is refusing my application:

```
const http = require('http');
const express=require('express');
const path=require("path");
const socketIo=require("socket.io");

var app=express();
var server=http.createServer(app);
var io=socketIo(server);




io.on("connection",(socket)=>{
console.log("New user connected");


 socket.on("Hello",(message)=>{
        console.log(message);
    });
  });


server.listen(3500,()=>{
   console.log("Server is up");
  });
```

That's also a simple android app MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Button send;
Button open;

public Socket mSocket;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button send=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sendData);
    final Button open=(Button)findViewById(R.id.open);
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.0.100:3500");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}

        Log.d("sadad","wqewq");

    }






    open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            mSocket.connect();

        }


    });


    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            HashMap<String,String> jsonData=new HashMap<>();
            jsonData.put("username","asdasdasdasdas");
            jsonData.put("company","asdasdsad");
            jsonData.put("job","asdasdsad");



            JSONObject object=new JSONObject(jsonData);

            mSocket.emit("Hello",object);
        }
    });



}

}
```

Also I looked at logs in android studio it is having a hard time to connect with no response sending many TCP connections waiting after the timeout:

```
D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=192.168.0.100; servname=(null); 
                                     cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null);  

  ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=192.168.0.100; servname=(null);  

cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0

D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4;
ai_family=0
```

Comment: Please make sure your mobile is connected to the same network as of  your system.

Comment: @user702827861 I'am connected bro

Comment: Can you connect your phone to Android Studio through wifi? If yes, then you are connected to same network

Comment: app.get('/api',function(req,res){
  res.json([{firstname:'john',lastname:'doe'}]);
        });  ive added this to the server and access it with link 192.168.0.100:3500/api using google chrome and it gave me a response @user702827861

Comment: so this doesn't mean you are connected to same network. Try to connect your mobile to Android Studio through Wifi.

Comment: @user702827861 connection is successful to android studio!!.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152223/discussion-between-abdallah-safieddine-and-user702827861).